# $.post result echoing HTML instead of value

Tags: php, html, ajax, post

Simple question here. I am getting the value of an HTML element and sending it via POST to the server using the following code. But when I alert the results instead of just the value I am also getting the HTML of the included PHP file. Why is this happening?

```
function postData(){
  let select_value = document.getElementById("selector").value;
  $.post('customer_order_form.php', { valor: select_value }, function(result) { 
      alert(result);
  });
}
```

The PHP code is very simple and it's just echoing the quantity for test purposes:

```
<?php include('includes/header.html'); 


if (isset($_POST["valor"]))
{
  $quantity = $_POST["valor"];
  echo $quantity;

} 
else 
{
  $quantity = null;
  echo "no quantity here";
}

?>
```

but on the callback function when I alert the result I get all the included file HTML code instead of the value, why is that?

[image]

Comment: I would imagine it has something to do with `include('includes/header.html');`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`include('includes/header.html');` is adding HTML to the page. When you do `$.post()` you are retrieving your header file. This include should not be inside of your file here.

Remove the `include` and everything should be fine.

Comment: Thank you very much sir